# AngularJS and Bootstrap: Red border on invalid input field on submit

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've this basic form implemented using AngularJS and Bootstrap:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/0stwd03k/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form class="well" name="formTest" ng-submit="save()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name*</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.save = function () {
    };
}
```

**Result**

[image]

The Name input field is required. When I click the submit button, I need the input field to have a red border if it's invalid. How can this be done?

Alternatively, if I unfocus the input field and it's still not valid, it would be great that the red corder is shown on that time, instead of waiting for the form submit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing you were missing was adding `ng-model='name'` to input field, then only will the form become invalid once you click submit, otherwise the form will always be valid since it considers that there is no field present.

Then I'd add the `submitted` class on the `submit` click button, then put the border css like `.submitted` would be the parent and `.ng-invalid` would be the child so we can put the style on `.submitted .ng-invalid`

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form class="well" name="formTest" ng-class="{'submitted': submitted}" ng-submit="save()" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name*</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" ng-model="name" required />
        </div>{{submitted}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitted= true;">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.submitted .ng-invalid{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0stwd03k/2/)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Pankaj Parker - How do we do same thing if the form elements don't have `required` tag attached to them? E.g. `<input type="input" ng-model="user.name">`. Thanks

Comment: I manager with `ng-class="vm.errors.name ? 'danger' : ''"` but if I have many fields then I'll have to add it to all which doesn't feel right! Any better solution?

Answer (score 16):

Twitter Bootstrap has an `has-error` class, so I would use this in conjunction with `ng-class` for the form group, then a label with the `label` and `label-danger` classes for good measure:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': errors.Name }">
    <label for="name">Name*</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required />
    <span class="label label-danger" ng-if="errors.Name">{{errors.Name}}</span>
</div>
```

Then in your controller, have an `errors` object, and set the `Name` property of this to a string when the name is invalid.

Comment: That is a pretty neat solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need angular to take over validation, so add `novalidate` to form. Also add `ng-class` to `input` field to determine wether to add error css

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="test()">
    <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required ng-class="myForm.user.$invalid && myForm.user.$dirty ? 'error' : ''">
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.    </span>
</span>

<p>
    <input type="submit"
    ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||
    myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
</p>
</form>
```

Good luck..